# Добавление данных в БД из DTO

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, automapper, dto

У меня есть класы entities для представление данных в БД и соответствующие DTO для передачи данных между слоями приложения.

```
    public class Dish
    {
        public int DishId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Index(IsUnique = true)]
        [StringLength(400)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public double PreparationTime { get; set; }

        public string Photo { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; } = new List<Category>();

        public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; } = new List<Ingredient>();

        public virtual ICollection<IngredientAmount> IngredientAmounts { get; set; } = new List<IngredientAmount>();

        public virtual ICollection<RecipeUnit> RecipeUnits { get; set; } = new List<RecipeUnit>();
    }
```

```
public class DishDetailedDTO: IDishDTO
    {
        public int DishId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(400)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public double PreparationTime { get; set; }

        public string Photo { get; set; }

        public List<CategoryDTO> Categories { get; set; }

        public List<IngredientDetailedDTO> Ingredients { get; set; }

        public List<IngredientAmountDTO> IngredientAmounts { get; set; }

        public List<RecipeUnitDTO> RecipeUnits { get; set; }

    }
```

```
public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Index(IsUnique = true)]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Dish> Dishes { get; set; } = new List<Dish>();
    }
```

```
    public class CategoryDTO: ICategoryDTO
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Проблема появляется когда я пытаюсь добавить новый обьект Dish, навигационное поле которого(например категория) уже есть в базе данных. Я получаю DishDetailedDTO из фронтенда, использую AutoMapper для получение обьекта Dish и добавляю Dish в соответствующий DbSet. Вот воспрозведение проблемы в меньшем масштабе:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(x=> 
            {
                x.CreateMap<Dish, DishDTO>();
                x.CreateMap<Dish, DishDetailedDTO>();
                x.CreateMap<Dish, DishAvailableIngredientsDTO>();
                x.CreateMap<DishDTO, Dish>();
                x.CreateMap<DishDetailedDTO, Dish>();
                x.CreateMap<DishAvailableIngredientsDTO, Dish>();
                x.CreateMap<Category, CategoryDTO>();
                x.CreateMap<CategoryDTO, Category>();
                x.CreateMap<Ingredient, IngredientDetailedDTO>();
                x.CreateMap<Ingredient, IngredientDTO>();
                x.CreateMap<IngredientDTO, Ingredient>();
                x.CreateMap<IngredientDetailedDTO, Ingredient>();
                x.CreateMap<IngredientAmount, IngredientAmountDTO>();
                x.CreateMap<IngredientAmountDTO, IngredientAmount>();
                x.CreateMap<RecipeUnit, RecipeUnitDTO>();
                x.CreateMap<RecipeUnitDTO, RecipeUnit>();
            });

            var context = new EFDbContext();

            var dish = new DishDetailedDTO()
            {
                Name = "SomeName",
                Categories = new List<CategoryDTO>
                { 
                   new CategoryDTO()
                   {
                       Name = "Breakfast"
                   }
                }
            };

            context.Dishes.Add(Mapper.Map<Dish>(dish));
            context.SaveChanges();

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

Во время вызова SaveChanges получаю исключение

```
SqlException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Categories' with unique index 'IX_Name'. The duplicate key value is (Breakfast).
The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: Ну как-бы в описании ошибки же всё написано... В таблице `Categories` столбец `Name` указан как уникальный и (разумеется) при попытке добавить ещё одну категорию `Breakfast` выкидывается исключение. Вот это уберите :`[Index(IsUnique = true)]` или `IsUnique = false`, если нужен индекс...

Comment: @XelaNimed Логично что не может быть двух категорий с одинаковым названием. Проблема в том, что оно пытается сразу добавить навигационную пропертю в бд, а не подставить ссылку на уже существующюю

Comment: А где у Вас ссылка на уже существующую? `new CategoryDTO(){ Name = "Breakfast" }` - это создаёт новый объект, а не ссылается на существующий. Для ссылки на существующий, Вам нужно выбрать его из БД.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В типе `Dish` Вы декорируете свойство `Name` и указываете, что индекс должен быть уникальным:

```cs
[Required]
[Index(IsUnique = true)]
[StringLength(400)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Укажите, что индекс не должен быть уникальным, если индекс Вам нужен, либо полностью его уберите:

```cs
[Required]
// Раскомментируйте, если индекс необходим
// [Index(IsUnique = false)]
[StringLength(400)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

---

Если Вы желаете добавить ссылку на уже существующую категорию, то её необходимо выбрать из БД, т.к. EF должен знать Id сущности для создания ссылки:

```cs
var cat = context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals("Breakfast"));
// convert cat to CategoryDTO catDto
var dish = new DishDetailedDTO() {
    Name = "SomeName",
    Categories = new List<CategoryDTO> { catDto }
};
```